# HandlerMethodArgumentResolver not being called

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi am trying to create a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. The problem i am facing is that  its methods are never called. Here is what i've done:

My argument resolver

```
public class ExternalUserDetailsArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return (parameter.getParameterAnnotation(ExternalUserDetails.class) != null);
}

public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    ExternalUserDetails userDetailsAnnotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(ExternalUserDetails.class);

    if (userDetailsAnnotation != null) {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        ExternalUser userDetails = (ExternalUser) auth.getPrincipal();
        return userDetails;
    }

    return null;

}

}
```

The annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ExternalUserDetails {
}
```

The configuration (no .xml configuration is used)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.base.package" })

public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    return new MultipartConfigElement("");
}

@Bean(name = "validator")
public Validator getStandardValidator() {
    return new org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(name = "userDetailsArgumentResolver")
public ExternalUserDetailsArgumentResolver userDetailsArgumentResolver() {
    return new ExternalUserDetailsArgumentResolver();
}

@Override
protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(userDetailsArgumentResolver());
}

}
```

When i start the application the MVCConfig is called and all it's @Bean annotated methods are called but the addArgumentResolvers doesn't get called.

In my controller i have this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
RequestInfo createRequest(@ExternalUserDetails ExternalUser userDetails , @RequestBody final RequestInfo request) {
//do something here
}
```

All i get is this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [my.base.package.controllers.RequestController]
Method [public my.base.package.RequestInfo my.base.package.controllers.RequestController.createRequest(my.base.package.ExternalUser,my.base.package.RequestInfo)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=my.base.package.AuthorizationImpl] [value=my.base.package.AuthorizationImpl@71724981]
[1] [type=my.base.package.RequestInfo] [value=my.base.package.RequestInfo@637ee57]

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:218)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:947)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:878)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

Here is the  AuthorizationImpl class

```
 public class AuthorizationImpl implements Authentication {

private ExternalUser user;
 // just a simple pojo with getters and setters
   }
```

Here is the  ExternalUser class

```
public class ExternalUser implements Principal {

private long id;

private String name;
// just a simple pojo with getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `AuthorizationImpl` class? Is that what the `userDetails` is in your `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`?

Comment: Let's see your `ExternalUser` type too.